# Creating a factory method returning generic

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, factory

I have an **abstract** `class` defined this way:

```
class BaseCoordinator<ResultType>
```

Other classes inherit from this one eg.

```
final class AppCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<Void>
final class AuthFlowCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<AuthFlowCoordinationResult>
final class MainFlowCoordinator: BaseCoordinator<Void>
```

Now I want to create a **factory** method. I guess it's sugnature should look like:

```
func makeCoordinator<T>() -> BaseCoordinator<T>
```

But, of course, I get error like this one:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'AppCoordinator' to return type 'BaseCoordinator<T>'
```

What Xcode suggests me is to add `as! BaseCoordinator<T>`, but I hate this force downcasting (and returning `?` isn't satisfying me either, as I'm 100% sure I'll have a correct default object), as I want assurance that *at least* a default `Coordinator` will be returned.
It feels like I'm missing something, but I really have no clue what is it. Is it actually possible to make such factory method, or is Swift generics limited?

Comment: How are you implementing the factory method? Do you just check what `T` is and returns an instance of the corresponding subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` must have a predefined type at compile time. Therefore you cannot choose `T` using the implementation of `makeCoordinator()` by returning different coordinators with different `ResultType`s.

In this case, the caller can choose which value he wants to assign to `T`, potentially breaking the function. For example the following two calls would be perfectly valid:

```
let coordinator: BaseCoordinator<Void> = makeCoordinator()
let coordinator: BaseCoordinator<[Int: [String]]> = makeCoordinator()
```

It would not make sense to use `[Int: [String]]` as a generic type but it is still possible. Depending on the generic type you choose at the function call, the cast may work or not, which is why a force cast will likely lead to a crash.

An optional cast, as suggested by Tom E would fix the potential crash but it would still not resolve this problem.

Therefore you cannot use a factory pattern for this without erasing `ResultType` to `Any` using a wrapper type, which would defeat the purpose of generics.

If you want type safety, you have to create a factory method for each subclass of `BaseCoordinator` you want to instantiate or just call their initializers manually.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `as?` instead of `as!`. The former yields an optional, i. e. the result will be nil if the cast doesn’t succeed. This way you have a safe cast without the need of forcing anything.

Comment: I know I can cast, but I'll have to return Optional.

Comment: Well, if you are “100% sure I'll have a correct default object” then I’d say it is totally justifiable to force cast the return type using `as!`.